# Add google Plus api and youTube api in objective c at the same time

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api, xcode4.3

I am working on a project in which I have to add google plus and youtube api's for iOS. The issue I am facing is that it gives some duplication error while linking:

duplicate symbol _kCharsToForceEscape

and the files it show redundant are:
GDataUtilities.o and GTLUtilities.o

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue, and you can't delete Gdata utilities or GLT Utility because they are called in almost every case in GDATA and the GLT. there is a way around this go to gdata utilities and go down to the part where it says #pragma mark string encoding look for this line of code:

```
const CFStringRef kCharsToForceEscape = CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]");
```

comment this out.

Then comment this part out:

```
  //CFStringRef escapedStr;
  //escapedStr = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
  //                                                     originalString,
  //                                                     leaveUnescaped,
  //                                                     kCharsToForceEscape,
  //                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
 // if (escapedStr) {
 //   resultStr = [(id)CFMakeCollectable(escapedStr) autorelease];
 // }
```

If will be in there twice make sure you comment both out.

Then run app.

It worked for me I seem to have youtube working and it seems to compile the google plus API OK.